# Windows Service : most appropriate location of the service specific files (database)

Tags: windows, windows-services, location

I have a windows service that hosts a WCF end-point that is a front-end for a SQL Server CE database.

At the moment I have it at:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

**Question**: what is most appropriate location for this file (`database.sdf`)?

Answer (score 0):

Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData is user-specific.  If you have an installer for your service, I'd create a traditional C:\Program Files\MyWCFService folder and store it there.

Comment: Good point. Though, doesn't writing in c:\ProgramFiles requires elevated privileges? Or would            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) make better choice, since it is not user specific?